# make like button by ajax in laravel (method=post)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to make like button in my laravel project by using ajax.

Would you please tell me what is wrong in my written code?

html part

```
<a id="bL-like-{{$file["User_Id"]}}-{{$file["id"]}}">like</a>
```

js

```
$("a").click(function() {
//like button
    if(this.id.startsWith("bL-like-")){
        var temp=this.id.substr(8);
        var l_user=temp.substr(0,(temp.indexOf("-")));
        var l_id=temp.substr((temp.indexOf("-")+1));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/like',
            data:{user:l_user,link_id:l_id},
            success:function(data){
                alert('liked');
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

route

```
Route::post('/like', array(
    'as'    => 'like',
    'uses'  => 'FileController@like'
));
```

FileController

```
public function like(Request $request)
{
    $OBJ=new \App\File();
    $OBJ->isActive=1;
    $OBJ->isDeleted=0;
    $OBJ->User_Id=$request['user'];
    $OBJ->id=$request['link_id'];
    $boolean=\App\File::increaseLike($OBJ);
}
```

increaseLike is in my model,that connect to db.

It always drives to error part of js.
I very appreciate if you help me.